# Microsoft Graph API for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to access MS Graph API for updating user details.
I am using below but the filter criteria doesn't seem to work
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=eq(extension_ce64b1571f694b84aeef256f85b7f49c_custom 'ABCD')

I am getting below error.
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid filter clause",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-08-18T18:28:26",
"request-id": "5bbdc288-02b5-4b80-9ef4-707c12b7af47"
}
}
}

Updating by objectid is not an option and we need to use the custom attribute.

Please help.

Comment: Filter is wrong

Comment: Can you please share the right filter. This is for update request.

Answer (score 1):

The filter syntax in your  request is incorrect. Please try below request which will fix your issue,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=(extension_f03e52a0a21349eebc055bbd0c920c0d_FavouriteSeason eq 'summer')
```

Comment: With https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=extension_ce64b1571f694b84aeef256f85b7f49c_custom eq ‘989898AB’ getting error.    {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-08-19T02:44:44",
            "request-id": "fbc85965-a572-4879-b873-3a05b8a67a81"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Hi Hari,Are you able to run it? I am getting error. {
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-08-19T13:43:44",
            "request-id": "4ce2a3a3-c636-4c28-8cff-19c16cf213f4"
        }
    }

Comment: Please try it with your query parameters and it is working for me .Also,If you are using for patch request then don't use filter.

Comment: Yes, I am using PATCH since I want to update by searching for a user using a unique custom attribute and not objectid.

Comment: @SushmitaDas You can try this. 
Try Get method to filter users based on extension attribute, fetch object id from it and then use that objectID to update the users.

Comment: It works this way but I wanted to know if there is way to just make one call and update the user.

Comment: Hi @SushmitaDas, It is not possible with MS Graph  in single call.